# Need to multiply rows based on Number column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my case there is a delivery of Product per Area according to Nos of allotment.

```
Rowstamp  DocNos  ProductID  SiteCode   SiteDesc      Qty
1         AAAA    1AA        0200       Mckinley Area  2
2         AAAA    1BB        0200       Mckinley Area  3
3         AAAA    1CC        0200       Mckinley Area  1
4         BBBB    1AA        0300       Southwoods     4
5         BBBB    1BB        0300       Southwoods     2
6         BBBB    1CC        0300       Southwoods     2
```

But now I need a single row for each element. This will be use for tagging of box of item individually. This is the output I want:

```
Rowstamp  DocNos  ProductID  SiteCode   Description    Qty  
1         AAAA    1AA        0200       Mckinley Area  1
1         AAAA    1AA        0200       Mckinley Area  1
2         AAAA    1BB        0200       Mckinley Area  1
2         AAAA    1BB        0200       Mckinley Area  1
2         AAAA    1BB        0200       Mckinley Area  1
3         AAAA    1CC        0200       Mckinley Area  1
4         BBBB    1AA        0300       Southwoods     1
4         BBBB    1AA        0300       Southwoods     1
4         BBBB    1AA        0300       Southwoods     1
4         BBBB    1AA        0300       Southwoods     1
5         BBBB    1BB        0300       Southwoods     1
5         BBBB    1BB        0300       Southwoods     1
6         BBBB    1CC        0300       Southwoods     1
6         BBBB    1CC        0300       Southwoods     1
```

Thank You For usual support!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple method uses a recursive subquery:

```
with cte as (
      select Rowstamp, DocNos, ProductID, SiteCode, Description, qty, 1 as num
      from t
      union all
      select Rowstamp, DocNos, ProductID, SiteCode, Description, qty, num + 1
      from cte
      where num <= qty
     )
select Rowstamp, DocNos, ProductID, SiteCode, Description, num as qty
from cte;
```

Comment: Above syntax not looking fine, we are not using word "cte" in second select query of recursive cte. Can you correct me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can join to a number table. Here I use a query on `sysobjects` from the `master` database, since it's always there and likely to have lots of rows. If you happen to have `qty` values that are bigger than the row count in `sysobjects`, there are other approaches to getting a source of numbers.

```
SELECT T.RowStamp, T.DocNos, T.ProductID, T.SiteCode, T.Description, T.qty
FROM T
  INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY id) AS num
        FROM master.dbo.sysobjects
        ) AS B
    ON B.num <= T.qty
```

Answer (score 0):

Cursor walk to create the recs:

```
CREATE TABLE #Tags
(
    [Rowstamp] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DocNos] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ProductID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SiteCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SiteDesc] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

Declare @RowStamp Int, @DocNos nVarChar(50),@ProductID nVarChar(50), @SiteCode nVarChar(50),@SiteDesc nVarChar(50),@Qty nVarChar(50)

DECLARE record_cursor CURSOR FOR  
  SELECT [Rowstamp], [DocNos], [ProductID], [SiteCode], [SiteDesc], [Qty]
  FROM [tbl_Tags];  

OPEN record_cursor;  

FETCH NEXT FROM record_cursor INTO
@RowStamp, @DocNos,@ProductID, @SiteCode, @SiteDesc, @Qty;  

Declare @vRecs Int
Set @vRecs = 0

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    While @vRecs < @Qty
    Begin
     Insert Into #Tags Values(@RowStamp, @DocNos,@ProductID, @SiteCode, @SiteDesc, 1)
     Set @vRecs = @vRecs+1
    End

    Set @vRecs = 0
    FETCH NEXT FROM record_cursor INTO @RowStamp, @DocNos,@ProductID, @SiteCode, @SiteDesc, @Qty;  
END  

Select * From #Tags 

Drop table #Tags
CLOSE record_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE record_cursor;
```